# Trying to run GeoFire Default Rules

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security, geofire

I am trying to setup default GeoFire Rules on Firebase.  When I turn on the rules below on the "geo" key I am getting "Permission Denied" in Xcode (SwiftUI). But other areas in firebase are getting written to.  It's just geoFire that is getting denied.   I want any Authed user to read/write to the entire firebase.

The "key" is an firebase random Key generator.
`let firebaseStoreRef = storeRef.childByAutoId()`

This link is where I am getting the default GeoFire rules
(https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/examples/securityRules/authenticated.rules.json)

Here is my JASON structure when I turned off the rules or set the rules to just auth.

```
{
  "geo" : {
    "-MAsyzawTChafkDQAzpx" : {
      "g" : "9r4bb5f5h6",
      "l" : [ 39.52796273493379, -119.8798737645459 ]
    },
    "-MAtFpjYsSLA0jJ4-5Le" : {
      "g" : "9r4bbk77v5",
      "l" : [ 39.5308423, -119.8671408 ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the rules that I setup in firebase.

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    "geo": {
       // Allow anyone to read the GeoFire index
      ".read": true,

      // Index each location's geohash for faster querying
      ".indexOn": ["g"],

      // Schema validation
      "$key": {
        // Allow any authentication user to add, update, or remove keys in the GeoFire index
        ".write": "auth !== null",

        // Key validation
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['g', 'l']) && newData.getPriority().length <= 22 && newData.getPriority().length > 0",

        // Geohash validation
        "g": {
          ".validate": "newData.val() == newData.parent().getPriority()"
        },

        // Location coordinates validation
        "l": {
          "0" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -90 && newData.val() <= 90"
          },
          "1" : {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() >= -180 && newData.val() <= 180"
          },
          "$other": {
            ".validate": false
          }
        },

        // Don't allow any other keys to be written
        "$other": {
          ".validate": false
        }
      }
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you authenticated?

Comment: Yes I am authenticated. The last line about ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null" will still write to another part of the database where the key is replicated with other information...  I commented out some of the rules, and it errors out if I don't comment out the validation.  Specifically, the code with the follow comments. 
// Key validation
// Geohash validation
// Don't allow any other keys to be written

Comment: If I comment out those areas it will allow the data to be written to the "geo" area, so it's not an auth issue.

Comment: Maybe creating an issue on their github might be an easier solution - allows their team to debug any rules which may be problematic.